# How to stop the site title from fading when scrolling?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to create a blog on wordpress and the theme is designed so whenever I scroll down the title of my blog slowly fades. I want to disable this but do not know the CSS code. Can anyone help? For reference the website is kylesjapan.life

Comment: Hey Kyle, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be easier for us to help if you can share the current code sample.

Comment: Hi I have the code css but it is too long for me to copy and paste. Is there a way I can upload txt documents?

Comment: You can add it to pastebin and share the link

Comment: Here is the pastebin for the original code. https://pastebin.com/BNbi1BeD
I cannot edit the source code however as I do not have have access to the business level of wordpress which is required to edit. I can however add my own CSS code.

Comment: it also came with a java script code that might be related to the issue I am having. https://pastebin.com/Rqg9P071 if anyone knows how to turn this off I would really appreciate it

Comment: looks like it worked! Please set the answer as right answer if it helped ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably this part of the javascript

```
$( '.site-branding' ).css({
    'opacity' : ( 1 - position / height * 2 )
});
```

remove this part, or change it to

```
'opacity' : 1
```